# Enabling Glimpse causes "Page not available"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-web-roles, glimpse, .net-4.5

To get some diagnostics for our MVC4 application (with an WebRole for Microsoft Azure) we installed [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/Docs/) through NuGet.

Everything went fine, but when I enable Glimpse through the `~/Glimpse.axd` page our application is completely unreachable. On every request we get the message "This Webpage is not available" (Chrome).

In the output window in Visual Studio 2013 I saw an error message which suggests to disable async support through the `web.config`:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Glimpse:DisableAsyncSupport" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

Unfortunately this is not helping. When we turn off Glimpse everything is just fine.

How can I find out what the problem is?

**Update**

The logs shows me this warning:

`WARN | Unable to locate '</body>' with content encoding 'Unicode (UTF-8)' for request. The response may be compressed or the markup may actually be missing a '</body>' tag.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found my solution on the [troubleshooting page of Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/Docs/Troubleshooting).

In short, url compression was applied so had to disable this in the web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="false" />
</system.webServer>
```